# why Oozie is not using NoSQL (e.g. HBASE, MongoDB) for its persistence mechanism?

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper, oozie

As stated by Oozie developer that one of the challenge in workflow management by Oozie is its SQL store that has known limitations in true scalability. And there are considering alternative technology for persistence storage (such as zookeeper). Why aren't they considering HBase, MongoDB or any other scalable NoSQL database for their purpose?

Comment: @Thilo: I guess this is place to ask question and if u don't know just don't bother to write a comment. Because of people like you users are moving towards Quora to get a decent reply.

Comment: This question is too specific to a organisation, the Oozie devs might frequent this site but I doubt it and even if they did it might not even be possible for them to state why the company is not moving in that direction due to liability. With this in mind I agree with @Thilo this is not a question that we can not factually answer on this site.

Comment: there is always a nicer way to put the point.

Comment: Oozie is Open Source project and they have stated its limitations so who are all working on Oozie might know the reason for not going with NoSQL till now but of course thay have planned to do so. So I don't think its organization specific question. Oozie is contributed by whole open source folks.

Comment: If you do open a thread on Quora, please link to it.